# libGDX changing button's image

Tags: java, android, libgdx

By following Kilbolt's Zombie Bird tutorial I created in my project a class to represent all buttons:

```
public class SimpleButton {

private float x, y, width, height;

private TextureRegion buttonUp;
private TextureRegion buttonDown;

private Rectangle bounds;

private boolean isPressed = false;

public SimpleButton(float x, float y, float width, float height,
        TextureRegion buttonUp, TextureRegion buttonDown) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.buttonUp = buttonUp;
    this.buttonDown = buttonDown;

    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

}

public boolean isClicked(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return bounds.contains(screenX, screenY);
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batcher) {
    if (isPressed) {
        batcher.draw(buttonDown, x, y, width, height);
    } else {
        batcher.draw(buttonUp, x, y, width, height);
    }
}

public boolean isTouchDown(int screenX, int screenY) {

    if (bounds.contains(screenX, screenY)) {
        isPressed = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean isTouchUp(int screenX, int screenY) {

    // It only counts as a touchUp if the button is in a pressed state.
    if (bounds.contains(screenX, screenY) && isPressed) {
        isPressed = false;
        return true;
    }

    // Whenever a finger is released, we will cancel any presses.
    isPressed = false;
    return false;
}
}
```

Whenever I want to create a button I do it in my InputProcessor class by creating a SimpleButton object and after filling its parameters I add it to List list.
My current problem is that I'm trying to create a sound button, which I did create and it work fine, but what I'm struggling with is making the button change TextureRegion between ON and OFF states.
This is an example of how I create a button(actually I created the sound button) and put it in the list:

```
    soundButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.soundOnNotClicked.getRegionWidth() / 0.25f),
            midPointY - 102, 15, 15, AssetLoader.soundOnNotClicked,
            AssetLoader.soundClicked);
    gameButtons.add(backButton);
```

I tried using the same condition that when sound ON is on it will put inside the parameters "AssetLoader.soundOnNotClicked" and when it's OFF "AssetLoader.soundOFFNotClicked", but it just show the first TextureRegion in the condition. Can someone help me figure out how I can change TextureRigions when sound is ON and OFF?

EDIT WITH CHANGES:
First created a second constractor:

```
public SimpleButton(float x, float y, float width, float height,
        TextureRegion buttonUp, TextureRegion buttonDown, TextureRegion buttonOn) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.buttonUp = buttonUp;
    this.buttonDown = buttonDown;
    this.buttonOn = buttonOn;

    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

}
```

Then changed a bit the isClicked method:

```
public boolean isClicked(int screenX, int screenY) {
    if (isOn == false) {
        isOn = true;
    }else {
        isOn = false;
    }
    return bounds.contains(screenX, screenY);
}
```

Then changed the draw method:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batcher) {
    if (isPressed) {
        batcher.draw(buttonDown, x, y, width, height);
    } else {
        if (isOn == false) {
            batcher.draw(buttonUp, x, y, width, height);
        }else{
            batcher.draw(buttonOn, x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly I changed the creation of the button by adding the textureRegion of the OFF sound:

```
    soundButton = new SimpleButton(
            136 / 2 - (AssetLoader.soundButtonOff.getRegionWidth() / 0.25f),
            midPointY - 102, 15, 15, AssetLoader.soundButtonOff,
            AssetLoader.soundButtonOn, AssetLoader.soundButtonOffX);
    menuButtons.add(soundButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make another boolean called isOn just like isPressed
2. Add another TextureRegion called buttonOn just like buttonDown
3. Add TextureRegion buttonDown to your constructor and set it there like you do with buttonDown
4. Flip the boolean whenever the button is clicked in isClicked(). (isOn = !isOn)
5. Add the condition in your draw method to draw the buttonOn texture if isOn is true.

That should pretty much do it.

Comment: You mean modifying the SimpleButton class? Can I create a second method named "SimpleButton" with different parameters (ones that fit what you suggest) and use it when creating the sound button?

Comment: You can either modify the SimpleButton class or make a new class called SimpleCheckButton that extends SimpleButton and has the differences I mentioned. And yes you could create a second constructor method with different parameters if you want.

Comment: So I tried to modify the SimpleButton class by creating the following changes you can see in the edit above. Please check them out and tell what I do wrong cause when the sound is OFF the ON's texture still remain...

Comment: Looks okay to me. I would try putting a breakpoint in the draw method and stepping through it. Just to make sure the isOn boolean is what you expect it to be. If the isOn seems to be working, make sure the 'on' texture isn't somehow the same as the 'up' texture (I've done that before). My guess is your isOn boolean is always set to true somehow. But again, I can only guess - if you use the debugger you'll find out what the problem is very quickly. It's not hard - if you're using eclipse just double click to the left of the line to make a breakpoint then use the debug button to run you game.

Comment: It seemed that the problem was with having two method with the same name (SimpleButton), and I believe it was because I created a few buttons, some using the first method and the sound one with the second and then adding them all to the same "List<SimpleButton>". When I picked only the new method and added the new parameter to the old buttons (which was unnecessary but harmless) everything started to work fine. So thank you if guiding me!

Comment: In your old constructor, you need to set buttonOn to buttonUp. That way it looks the same whether it is on or off.